# 〜ていない vs 〜ないでいる

Tags: grammar, て-form

I read many times [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13635/%E3%80%9C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-verb-ending) but I'm still confused about the differences between these two grammars. The first answer says that `〜ていない` has a possible third meaning not used, "*I eat my meal and I am here (/I exist)*" that is "*a terrible way to read it*", and when it goes to explain `〜ないでいる`, it means "*I am here (/I exist) without eating my meal.*" which seems very similar to the terrible way of reading it.

Also, wouldn't `ていない` mean **"... and I'm not here"?**
I appreciate the efforts of the person who answered, but I really didn't understand it, especially what **"instrumental adjunct"** is.

I'm not sure, but the difference between them seems to be how long the state remains.

In `食べていない` I don't eat something since a long time ago, it remains until now and it will remain in the future, `食べないでいる` on the other hand, would mean that I'm in the state of not eating now, but that won't last too long.

The sentence that made me search about this grammar is: `僕が…書けないでいるから？`  It's an answer from person A to person B when asked why the person A is in the same place as B.

Could someone explain the differences between these two grammars and when should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without complete predicate, it is hard to generalize the difference between 〜ないでいる and 〜ていない. So, I'd like to use `食べていない` and `食べないでいる` from your example.

And, I have not understood what "instrumental adjunct" states clearly,but I'd like to answer.

The author in the link might be explaining the sentence : `食事を食べないでいる` implies "I want to be in the state of not eating ( in order to lose the weight, etc. )" by stating *"I am here (/I exist) by not eating my meal." (instrumental adjunct)*

I mean *"I am here by not eating my meal"* implies to complete some purposes of its action. So, `食事を食べないでいる` implicitly modifies some purpose such as losing the weight, etc.

Consider the sentence `膝{ひざ}を怪我{けが}しているので、走{はし}らないでいる。` "*Due to the knee injury, I try not to run ( the purpose : in order to get recovery in the knee, etc. ).*"

So, your sentence : `僕が…書けないでいるから？` is possibly saying "I am here probably because I could not write ( Due to the slump, person A does not have an idea how to finish writing. )".

`食べていない` implies basically "not eating at this moment". It might imply habitual action, progressive action, experiences, etc. such as "*I do not eat X recently*", "*I am not touching the food to start eating*", "*I have not eaten since this morning.*", etc.

So, `膝{ひざ}を怪我{けが}しているので、走{はし}っていない。` could imply *"I do not run regularly due to the knee injury"*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to confirm, 〜ないでいる is a state that is implicitly related to one purpose, like "首にされたしお金ないので、最近何も買わないでいる"? I hope my example sentence is correct. Also, the author of the other answer mentioned the "state adjunct" by "I am here (/I exist) without eating my meal". Do you think there is a difference between those two explanations?

Comment: I think your sentence :  "首にされたしお金ないので、最近何も買わないでいる"?, which means "I got fired and have no money, so I haven't been buying anything." in most case. And I think I was taught translating "I am here (/I exist) without eating my meal." into 「自分の食事を食べずにいる。」from English into Japanese.　So, I do not have as strong correspondence as what the author's explanation「食事を食べないでいる」:  *I am here (/I exist) without eating my meal." (state adjunct)* probably unless I understand what the grammar term "state adjunct" means.

Comment: I see... well, thank you very much for helping me!