# Why is で used in 健康でいられる but not に？ Is this an adverb?

Tags: particle-で

I'm really confused about this one, does it mean "Stay healthy"? But if it does mean that shouldn't it be に instead of で？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

健康 is a na-adjective, and ～でいる is the correct way to say "to stay [state]". でいられる is its potential form.

- [What is the difference between でいる and である in this example?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66270/5010)
- [What is the meaning/grammar behind noun + でいる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62732/5010)
- [～ないでいる verb ending](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13635/5010)

> 健康でいられる
> to be able to stay healthy

～にいる means "to be at/in [place]" (e.g., 日本にいる = "to be in Japan"), but 健康 is not a place.