# 〜ず versus 〜ないで　(and maybe also in the case of adjectives, 〜なくて）

Tags: words

Consider the following example sentence (taken from an exercise sheet):

> 熱が下がらず苦しかった。

Now consider this sentence I made:

> 熱が下がらないで苦しかった。

What is the difference?

Comment: @snailboat I consider the verb version and the adjective version of the て-binding of sentences the same. Like "Xをしないで、Y" (without doing X, Y) and "楽しくて、面白かった" (it was enjoyable and entertaining). They are both "and" in English. But maybe I don't really understand it right. In any case: I will change the title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of saying the same thing:

> 熱が下がら**ず**苦しかった。 - literary or stiff expression
>   熱が下がら**なくて**苦しかった。 - casual / conversational.
>   熱が下がら**ないので**苦しかった。 - using explicit ので "because".

I think ～ないで is used mostly for: ① negative imperative: "さわらないで！" (milder than さわるな！) ② in the form of ～ないでいる and ～ないでおく: "今は言わないでおこう" ③ before various verbs: "顔も洗わないで行っちゃった". In cases ② and ③, ないで can be substituted with ずに.

Based on these, 熱が下がら**ないで**苦しかった and 熱が下がら**ずに**苦しかった are both understandable but sound slightly clumsy or unnatural, perhaps because 苦しかった is not a verb. With a verb instead, 熱が下がらないで苦しんだ and 熱が下がらずに苦しんだ are both fairly correct (except that 苦しんだ is rather a literary expression).

Comment: ② could be generalized to any 補助動詞, no? Also, I think 「熱が下がらず苦しんだ」 (that is, with no に) can still work with the same reading as the に version (in addition to the conjunctive reading), can't it?

Comment: Actually ないでいる / ないでおく are negative counterparts of ている / ておく (Compare: 彼は寝ている "He is sleeping", 彼は寝ていない "He is not sleeping", and 彼は寝ないでいる "He is staying up"). So I think you can say they are kinds of 補助動詞, though I don't know how most textbooks say about this.

Comment: And yes, 熱が下がらず苦しんだ is pretty natural too.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answer, I was taught that 〜なくて can imply a a causal relationship, while 〜ないで doesn't.

> 電車に乗れなくて、遅刻した。　- I was late because I couldn't get on the train.
>   シャワーを浴びないで、家を出た。　- I left the house without taking a shower. (but not because)

In these examples, the two are not interchangeable as far as I know.

Also, as the other answer mentioned, 〜ないでください is the standard form for negative imperative / requests and can't be substituted by 〜ず or 〜なくて.

Comment: More on 「〜なくて」 vs 「〜ないで」 can be found in [ないで vs なくて: combining phrases with negative verbs](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5925/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7-vs-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6-combining-phrases-with-negative-verbs) -- not sure that's exactly what the OP was asking about though.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Yes, thank you, this is helpful to me.