# Choosing between でも/ても with たい

Tags: particle-でも

How would you translate this sentence in Japanese?

> I don't want to work but then I can't live.

I have two options:

> 働きたくないでも生きれない

or

> 働きたくなくても生きれない

I have some doubts as I read that たい tends to act like an adjective. Thus, なくても  can be used here, expressing some kind of *connection/reasoning*.

On the other hand, ないで is usually used after negative forms of verbs. But is 働きたくない a verb or and adjective here?

Could you tell me, what is better to choose?

Comment: In the first place I am not sure ～ても is what you want. And where did you get this sentence? Did you make it yourself? While 生きれる is a valid potential form of 生きる, it's very informal, so I'd be surprised to see it rather than 生きられる in a textbook. (Granted I think 生きていけない here would work better than plain 生きられない)

Comment: Related: [ないで vs なくて: combining phrases with negative verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5925/%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7-vs-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a6-combining-phrases-with-negative-verbs/5926#5926)