# why the usage of ないでも in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-でも

タダならべつに勝たないでもよかろう
How would the nuances change if i said タダならべつに勝たなくてもよかろう?

Comment: In this particular case, there is no difference. In general, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5925/5010

Comment: Hey, i read the post, but it actually left me with little bit of confusion, the guy says that if you are about to use these adverbially, you must use ないで, but then he provides example : 何もしないで暖かくする  and says its ambiguous, why? isnt it used adverbially here?

Comment: Um, that 何もしないで暖かくする may not be a good example... I agree that XないでY is basically closer to "Y without X" and XなくてY is closer to "not X, so/and Y", though. Other examples include "最近彼を見なくて寂しい (I don't see him recently and I miss him)", "見ないで当てた (I guessed it correctly without looking at it)".

Comment: so the 何もしないで暖かくする is wrong? (in terms of being natural) i had the interpretation that 何もしないで暖かくする is "to stay warm without doing anything" and 何もしなくて暖かくする means "i dont do anything, so i stay warm"  am i correct? i think this is kind of weird example, since i completely understand why 最近彼を見なくて寂しい-  ( 寂しい being non-volitional result of whats before )is normal and  最近彼を見ないで寂しい (ないで here doesnt work as that "reason" marker) not. but i dont exactly understand why 何もしないで暖かくする is wrong. or well, "ambiguous"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the particular sentences, there are little differences, but base on the explanations of [this website](https://cotohajime.net/2021/01/21/naide-vs-nakute/),

> ＊「ないで」は行為をしない、ということを言っています。
>
> (ないで means *not doing the action*)

So,

> べつに勝たないでもよかろう

sounds about the will of the player(?). *You don't have to try to win*.

On the other hand,

> べつに勝たなくてもよかろう

sounds more about the state/result of winning/losing: *It is ok if you lose*.

---

To give another example,

- お金がなくても新しいiPhoneがほしい I want a new iPhone even if I don't have money

is normal. But

- お金がないでも新しいiPhoneがほしい

sounds a little odd because having money is not an action. (Note that 'お金がない. でも新しいiPhoneがほしい' is a perfectly normal sentence where でも is used a conjunction).

Answer (score 1):

Japanese is a lot about tone. Semantically these two mean the same, but the former is more straight and may sound a bit harsh. However, this depends heavily on the context.